# Use bibliography numbers and citation from other file

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, external-files

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`xcite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcite)

I want to reference to citations from other file. Similar to what `xr package` does to labels, but I want to apply it for the bibliography.

If I'm able to do `\cite{someone}` in the main file, and it creates let say the number [4], I want to do the same `\cite{someone}` in a second file, and also create the same number [4]. Similar to what `xr` does with the labels.

By the way, I tried to add the `main.bbl` file from the main file. However, that adds all the references to the end of the second file. I want to avoid this.

Is there any package that accomplish this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Save the following in your working directory as `xc.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{xc}
         [2011/09/02 v0.1 eXternal Citations (DPC+EG)]
\def\externalcitedocument{\@ifnextchar[\XC@{\XC@[]}}
\def\XC@[#1]#2{{%
  \makeatletter
  \def\XC@prefix{#1}%
  \XC@next#2.aux\relax\\}}
\def\XC@next#1\relax#2\\{%
  \edef\XC@list{#2}%
  \XC@loop{#1}}
\def\XC@aux{%
  \ifx\XC@list\@empty\else\expandafter\XC@explist\fi}

\def\XC@explist{\expandafter\XC@next\XC@list\\}
\def\XC@loop#1{\openin\@inputcheck#1\relax
  \ifeof\@inputcheck
    \PackageWarning{xc}{^^JNo file #1^^JLABELS NOT IMPORTED.^^J}%
    \expandafter\XC@aux
  \else
    \PackageInfo{xc}{IMPORTING LABELS FROM #1}%
    \expandafter\XC@read\fi}
\def\XC@read{%
  \read\@inputcheck to\XC@line
  \expandafter\XC@test\XC@line...\XC@}
\long\def\XC@test#1#2#3#4\XC@{%
  \ifx#1\bibcite
    \bibcite{\XC@prefix#2}{#3}%
  \else\ifx#1\@input
     \edef\XC@list{\XC@list#2\relax}%
  \fi\fi
  \ifeof\@inputcheck\expandafter\XC@aux
  \else\expandafter\XC@read\fi}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `xc.sty'.
```

Then say, in your `derived.tex` document,

```
\externalcitedocument{main}
```

(where `main.tex` is the document you are taking the citations from). Now

```
\cite{xyz}
```

in `derived.tex` will do what you want.

The interface is just the same as **xr**'s: you can also specify a prefix

```
\externalcitedocument[A-]{main}
```

and use `\cite{A-xyz}` in `derived.tex`.

The `xc.sty` file has been obtained from `xr.sty` with some very simple transformations:

1. `xr` -> `xc`
2. `XR` -> `XC`
3. `\externaldocument` -> `\externalcitedocument`
4. `\newlabel` -> `\bibcite`

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like charm. Why this isn't a default package? It's great! :)

Comment: A package (called **xcite**) is on its way to CTAN

Comment: The **xcite** package is on CTAN, waiting for TeX Live to add it, too.

Comment: Are there plans to make this work with `hyperref` (similar to `xr-hyper`)?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner It appears that xr-hyper is provided by hyperref. In fact, hyperref contains some code that complements xr-hyper.

Comment: @egreg I fact the suggestion of Joachim can be easily done. First, the external documents and the prefixes must be the same so that the part encoded in hyperref does not need to be modified. Second, we must know how hyperref manages bibcite label. I could check the first point. But I have no idea for the second. Do you have any hint ?

Comment: Hi @egreg, I think this only works with bibtex, correct? Does something similar exist for biblatex-biber combination?

Comment: @Fato39 The `xcite` package has actually been dismissed as its functionality has been taken over by `xr`. There's no support for `biblatex`, sorry.

Comment: I understand, thanks, @egreg!

Answer (score 1):

## BibLaTeX/Biber

The package `xcite` is now a part of [`xr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) and it works just the way you want if you use `bibtex`.
If you use `BibLaTeX`/`Biber`, the bibliography is not compiled using `\bibitem`s.

Instead, you can first compile both the main and the derived document and then simply copy `main.bbl` and rename it `derived.bbl`. Recompile the derived document, skipping `Biber` this time and you will get the references numbered as in the main document.

The downside of this manual method is that you always need to remember to copy the main bibliography file, whereas `xr` would take care of everything for you automatically.