# Multiple LaTeX files using the same bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have multiple different LaTeX files each which draw their bibliography from the same `.bib` file.  When they compile I want them to share one bibliography file that is a separate PDF file.  For example assume I have

```
one.tex
two.tex
three.tex
bibliography.bib
```

I want to create

```
one.pdf
two.pdf
three.pdf
bibliography.pdf
```

Where neither `one.pdf`, `two.pdf` nor `three.pdf` have their own bibliography in them, but instead all reference the same `bibliography.pdf` file. Is this possible to do, and if so how?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write a `bibliography.tex` file containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

and compile it (LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX). Then `one.tex` and the others can be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcite}
\externalcitedocument{bibliography}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Note that the **xcite** package was born from a question here on TeX.SX: [Use bibliography numbers and citation from other file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/use-bibliography-numbers-and-citation-from-other-file)

Instead of saying `\nocite{*}` in `bibliography.tex` you can gather the requested citations from your files by a simple shell one-liner

```bsh
grep -h citation one.aux two.aux three.aux | sed /citation/s//nocite/ > cites.tex
```

and say `\input{cites}` in `bibliography.tex` instead of `\nocite{*}`.

### A bit of explanation

When LaTeX finds a `\cite` command, it writes it in the `.aux` file for possible later processing with BibTeX. So `\cite{xyz}` will produce a line in the `.aux` file of the form

```
\citation{xyz}
```

In the presented case you have a big `.bib` file and want that only actually cited entries are extracted from it. But the entries are scattered among three files to be compiled independently and possibly not each of them will cite all the requested entries.

So the strategy is to delay bibliography typesetting until all the citations are present in the three `.aux` files. They will show the typical **??** in the text, but this is unimportant.

The `bibliography.tex` file will be of the form

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{cites}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

and we will populate a `cites.tex` file with the necessary BibTeX keys. The one-liner

```bsh
grep -h citation one.aux two.aux three.aux | sed /citation/s//nocite/ > cites.tex
```

will find all `\citation{...}` lines in the three `.aux` files; they will be filtered by `sed` that will change `\citation` into `\nocite` and the output will be written in `cites.tex` that will consist of lines of the form

```
\nocite{abc}
\nocite{def}
...
```

with all the cited entry keys. Now we can run LaTeX on `bibliography.tex`, then BibTeX and then LaTeX again. This will produce the correct `bibliography.aux` file that LaTeX will read (via the **xcite** package) when typesetting `one.tex`, `two.tex` and `three.tex` again.

Comment: This is definitely the simplest solution, and it only requires making a separate `.bib` file containing only the citations used by the actual documents.  But for those of us (including Jon) who have one big mega `.bib` file it doesn't really work.

Comment: I'm confused by your shell one liner, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jon The one liner is in response to my comment. (And your comment about having a global `.bib` file). It strips out the citations from each of the subdocuments and puts them into a file so that you can use a global bib file.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume the following:

- `one.tex`, `two.tex` and `three.tex` have the following structure:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  % preamble content
  \begin{document}
  % document content
  \bibliography{bibliography}% expects file "bibliography.bib"
  \end{document}
  ```
- You are using `bibtex`

Here are the steps you need to do in order to obtain your required output

1. `pdflatex one`
2. `bibtex one`
3. `pdflatex one`
4. `pdflatex one`
5. Comment out the line `\bibligoraphy{bibliography}`
6. `pdflatex one`
7. Repeat steps 1-6 for `two.tex` and `three.tex`
8. Construct `bibliography.tex` having

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   % preamble content
   \pagestyle{empty}% If needed
   \begin{document}
   \nocite{*}% Include all references in bibliography.bib
   \bibliography{bibliography}% expects file "bibliography.bib"
   \end{document}
   ```
9. Repeat steps 1-3 for `bibliography.tex`

Step 5 removes *only* the printing of the bibliography in the documents, while still keeping the references in place. During this step, the `.aux` file is overwritten, but the original values contained within are still used/available.

Step 8 can vary greatly, depending on the typesetting output of your `bibliography.pdf` file. For example, if you want page numbers, or headers/footers. I've included `\pagestyle{empty}` assuming that you want no header or footer.

Comment: When I run this I get no output, bibliography.pdf just says References at the top and then has no content.  What could be causing this?

Comment: So it worked for `one.tex`, `two.tex` and `three.tex`? Did you do `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` for `bibliography.tex`?

Comment: Right now I'm only testing it with one.tex just to make sure that it works.  I get one.tex without a bibliography like I want, but no references.  Yes I am doing those steps, here is a copy of my bibliography.text

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[top=1.27cm, bottom=1.27cm, left=1.27cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}

Comment: Just to be clear I ran > pdflatex bibliography > bibtex bibliography > pdflatex bibliography

Comment: @Jon: I'll look into this tonight when I'm home and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, just so more information, when running bibtex bibliography I get the following output, which I assume is no good. This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (MiKTeX 2.8)
The top-level auxiliary file: bibliography.aux
The style file: plain.bst
I found no \citation commands---while reading file bibliography.aux
Database file #1: bibliography.bib
(There was 1 error message)

Comment: @Jon: Seeing @ egreg's suggestion, does adding `\nocite{*}` in `bibliography.tex` solve the references issue? His solution may be more elegant since it doesn't involve the obscure removal of the `\bibliography` command. However, it may also depend on your specific instance.

Comment: That worked perfectly with the \nocite{*}.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

If the `.bib` file will only be used for those three `.tex` files, and you're willing to use `biblatex`, it seems pretty easy to do.

For the three `.tex` files, cite the `bibkeys` from your `.bib` file as normal, but do not include the `\printbibliography` command in the `.tex` files.  Then, in a fourth file, you just need to use the `\nocite{*}` and the `\printbibliography` command for it to print every entry from the bibfile.

Thus, the skeleton of your first three files would be:

```
\documentclass{<whatever>}
\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<bibfile.bib>}
\begin{document}
\cite{<key1>}% etc., etc.
\end{document}
```

while your master bibliography files will be:

```
\documentclass{<whatever>}
\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<bibfile.bib>}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The essential point: this `.bib` file must only contain entries that are found in your three other `.tex` files!  (Easily extracted from a `masterbibliography.bib` file through tools like `bibtool`, etc.

Comment: The problem is that we have one global .bib file that has many references that I do not want to include.

Comment: @Jon --- that is precisely the point of `bibtool`: it extracts all citations given in the `.aux` file and prints them to a new file (usage: `bibtool -x masterfile.aux -o newbibfile.bib`).  It is therefore quite easy to create a new `.bib` file from any number of 'master' bibliography files.

Answer (score 2):

do all the `.tex` files reference exactly the same `\cite`s?  (this point isn't clear in the question.)

if they do, then the other answers should work.

if they don't, the only way i can see to get a common bibliography is, in each `.tex` file, to include `\nocite{<key>}` for each entry that should be included, or, if the `.bib` file includes *only* the desired items, then `\nocite{*}` can be used instead.

going one step further, you could create a single `.tex` file containing only the `\nocite` instructions, and `\input` it to the other three `.tex` files.

this doesn't give you a separate pdf file, but it does give you the same bibliography content for all three tex jobs.