# How should I use and refer to the same bib database from writing several different latex documents?

Tags: bibliographies

I have several papers using the same 10 papers as in reference. Is there any way that one can just set up one bib database and use it for reference for all latex documents?

There has been some discussion on this solution previously, but I could not follow that. Can some one give straight-forward steps to set this up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple LaTeX files using the same bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36859/multiple-latex-files-using-the-same-bibliography)

Comment: @MMA I am not sure this is really a duplicate to the linked question. There, the OP requested to have the bibliography in *one* single PDF file to be reused for multiple documents; here, there's not explicit mention to a single PDF file containing the bibliography. Perhaps there's a better candidate for duplicate?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, you are right. I was in a bit of haste at that time. Is there a way I can edit my vote?

Comment: @MMA I don't know. Perhaps, if the question gets closed, we can vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your references in one .bib file. Then include this file in all 10 papers with the `\bibliography{}` command.

The problem may be that you do not want to put all papers in one folder. The most convenient way is to create one folder with 10 subfolders (each containing one of your projects). At the top level you put your .bib-file. Now you have to tell LaTeX that the .bib-file is one directorylevel up. This is easy done with `..`.

`\bibliography{../myreferences.bib}` tells LaTeX that is has to look one level up.

Assuming that you are new to BibTeX: have a look at the JabRef GUI and the `biblatex` package - both are useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works out! I am indeed 6 months new to BibTex. I will read your reference.