# Generate one bibliography from multiple LaTeX files

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

My question is similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36859/multiple-latex-files-using-the-same-bibliography) but with biblatex and biber backend.  As said in the title I want to generate one unified bibliography from two stand-alone LaTeX files, each of which have their own references.  The use case is for grant submission for example, during which, they typically ask for one document for all references.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use bibtool to extract the citations from each from the bib file or bib files you're using, put them in a single bib file, and then make a new document with `\nocite{*}` to include everything found in the bib file. Not sure if that matches your workflow, however.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need. If the bibliography of one document is a subset of the other something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426964/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473444/35864 might work.

Comment: Sorry for my late response.  
@frabjous Thanks, I will give bibtool a try.  Can you point me to a detailed guide to do so?

Comment: @moewe No, they are not necessary subset.  They might have common references though.  As I mentioned in the OP, the use case is for NIH grant proposal: I have multiple documents (applicant background and goals, research strategy, etc.) and one bibliography document which should list all the references in other documents.

Comment: Bibtool's [documentation](http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/bibtool.pdf) is pretty exhaustive. But a basic use to extract the bib entries used in a given tex file would be something like `bibtool -x filename.aux -o extracted.bib` (assuming the tex file is `filename.tex` and has been processed at least once by LaTeX to create the aux file). To do more than one file `bibtool -d -x filename.aux -x filename2.aux -o extracted.bib`

Comment: @frabjous Great, thanks. One question, how the references will be numbered correctly in the two LaTeX files filename.tex and filename2.tex?