# use the same bibliography bib file for two latex source (main and appendix)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a main latex source and its bibtex file: `./main.tex` and  `./main.bib`

In `main.tex` the bibliography is included as `\bibliography{main}`, then the pdf is correctly produced with all the needed references at the end.

Then I have a subdirectory and the appendix latex file: `./add/appendix.tex`, which is a standalone latex source. In this document I would like to share (some of) the `../main.bib` references, but keeping the main document numbering. Besides, a bibliographic section is only required in the main.

Including `\bibliography{../main.bib}` and running `$ bibtex appendix` gets the wrong numbering actually, restarting from one.

My problem is actually a bit different of what described here: [Multiple LaTeX files using the same bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36859/multiple-latex-files-using-the-same-bibliography)
or here:
[Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98660/two-bibliographies-one-for-main-text-and-one-for-appendix)
but still I did not find the solution.

Comment: For me, Herbert's answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660/21591 is exactly what you are looking for. How does your `appendix.tex` look like (it seems to be a standalone document)? Does it have a `\bibliographystyle{}` specification? Do you run `bibtex` on it?

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to get the references working now in the appendix running bibtex on it (I will edit the question). Still, it is not what I am looking for. `appendix.tex` is a standalone document, and I want to share (some of) the references of the main and especially the numbering must be the same. Besides, while a bibliography section is included in the main, in the appendix resulting document is not required.

Comment: This is a useful clarification, in particular that you want the same numbering. Please edit your question!

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I did it.

Answer (score 3):

I have find a possible solution, inspired from here: [Use bibliography numbers and citation from other file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/use-bibliography-numbers-and-citation-from-other-file)

So using the package `xc` in `appendix.tex`, like:

```
\usepackage{xc}
\externalcitedocument[m-]{../main}
```

and then citing using same labels as in `main.tex`, the numbering is actually the same and no bibliography appears in `appendix.tex`.
So to cite `XX` from `main.tex` in `appendix.tex` one should do:

```
\cite{m-XX}
```

that works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The `xc` package solution above does not seem to work for me (the main.tex uses biblatex, not bibtex, and that may have something to do with it). I see no evidence of main.bbl or main.aux being read from appendix.tex.

What does work is a `\makeatletter\input main.aux\makeatother` in appendix.tex, and replacing all the `\cite{foo}` in appendix.tex by `[\ref{foo}]`.

I'd really like to handle comma-separated references, but my latex skills are too rusty for that hack.